# How to prevent other from tampering response msg in HTTPS?

Tags: https, private-key

In HTTPS, only server hold the private key and is able to decode the message. 
My doubt is whether server will encode the response before sending it to client?
If so, how does the client decode it, since it does not have the private key?
If not, how does it prevent others from tampering the response message?

Comment: There are many good descriptions of how HTTPS works on the eInternet, study some for details. For an overview, the data is not encrypted with asymmetric (public/private key) encryption, it is encrypted with symmetric encryption such as AES, the symmetric key is encrypted with asymmetric encryption. Of course it is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my question by myself. The server will encrypt the response with public-key and send it to client. Other than that, the server will send a checksum as well, which acts as the signature. The checksum is generated based on the private-key that only server knows, therefore it is hard for others to fabricate it. Thus, if anyone trying tampering the message, it won't match the checksum.

Comment: It's almost the idea. It's  the base of public key cryptography